# How to create a new database at runtime in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I´m writing an app in Django and I have this specific requirement that every user should have their own independent database using the existing models in the app. The flow should be like this:

1(register new user) -> 2(Create the new database) -> 3(register Django DB list).

Until now I have managed to solve the 1st and 3rd part but the second is causing me some troubles.What should be the better(right) approach to solve this problem?

P.S Sorry for my awful English.

Comment: why don't you try posting on elance?